# jQuery UI Accordion - Fixed Height within HTML5 App

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to implement a vertical Accordian into a HTML5 IOS app side panel.  The accordion needs to fit the phones height exactly and any tab content thats larger than the panel should scroll.

I'm trying to implement (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default), but the content always flows out of the page and I cannot get it to fix the height,  - does anyone know how to do this or can offer any suggestions to put me on the right path!?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - set a height on the surrounding div - apply the following to the trigger -

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#notifPanelAcordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "fill"
        }
    );
});
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing the Accordion into a Div and setting its Height to be the same as the screen height by using an @media query in the CSS. for example:

**Index.html**

```
<div class="accordContainer">
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.css**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-height:800px){
    .accordContainer{
        height:800px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-height:480px){
    .accordContainer{
        height:480px;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested these yet as i still need to research more about CSS media queries and mobile devices, but it should provide a base to work from.

As for the scrolling, you could look into [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) 4.0, I'm using it in my project and it gives a nice scrolling effect to specific parts of a page (although I am using a JQueryMobile compatible version).